Passing Additional Information in LangChain abatch Calls
Given an abatch call for a LangChain chain, I need to pass additional information, beyond just the content, to the function so that this information is available in the callback, specifically in the on_chat_model_start method.
Here is the code:
    from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
    from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
    
    class ModelAsyncHandler(AsyncCallbackHandler):
        def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
        async def on_chat_model_start(
            self, serialized: Dict[str, Any], messages: List[List[BaseMessage]], run_id: UUID, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
            await asyncio.sleep(0.3)
            # How to get here additional data from the abatch call?
    

    model_async_handler = ModelAsyncHandler()    
    model = ChatOpenAI(
                api_key="API_KEY",
                model="MY_MODEL",
            )
    prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template("A sample template")
    llm_chain = prompt | model
    responses = await llm_chain.abatch(
                            inputs=[{"topic": "MY_CONTENT_1"}, {"topic": "MY_CONTENT_2"}],
                            config={'callbacks': [model_async_handler]},
                       )

This additional information could include the origin of the documents (such as file names). I couldn't find another way to include this information other than through the inputs parameter of the abatch function. The same issue applies to batch, invoke, or similar calls.
Does anyone else have the same problem and a smart solution for it?
